# Why does pasting the contents of a tikz file into my main file compile properly but not when using \input

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, matlab2tikz

If I place the contents of my `tikz` picture in my main.tex file it works like a charm using

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
    \tikzexternalize
```

and subsequently:
pdflatex --enable-shell

```
  \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
       \usepgfplotslibrary{external}
    \tikzexternalize
    \begin{document}
    \definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0,0.75,0.75}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[%
    width=4.52083333333333in,
    height=3.565625in,
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0, xmax=6,
    xlabel={cfu (Y)},
    ymin=0, ymax=1,
    ylabel={Probability density},
    legend style={draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left}
    ]
    \addplot [
    color=blue,
    solid,
    line width=1.5pt
    ]
    table{
    0.164920894751145 0.145245471693298
    0.34898483521757 0.314105513485571
    0.400206868657802 0.375704063846473
    0.431202365194672 0.415565960090126
    0.468283168514601 0.465368046385591
    0.468819173063357 0.466102333522882
    0.541086963948335 0.567617590141928
    0.558035142464694 0.591815958738304
    0.558424656178589 0.592372256340699
    0.567763246195775 0.605704754250354
    0.588442297122976 0.635140815037755
    0.588968308388865 0.635887013738116
    0.589496900268574 0.636636709024852
    0.615575125108802 0.673361419528354
    0.656478830152384 0.729356371745445
    0.663734249176834 0.739001710618186
    0.681134429788414 0.761691427683771
    0.699206339854542 0.784509230520803
    0.703174714510729 0.789406773282464
    0.710293205919594 0.798082837552696
    0.738324318268112 0.830765143080553
    0.743729355370618 0.836772857231647
    0.7628624687978 0.857202030543563
    0.789650071275085 0.883431847212714
    0.848769035460717 0.93014828764704
    0.857054257851899 0.935346913150545
    0.867490832222506 0.941393771927579
    0.892221633180695 0.953428704494102
    0.910732799951076 0.96026629015755
    0.942439202692875 0.967534739622871
    0.964173551423469 0.969220797343017
    0.966490207360103 0.969241291138126
    0.972340307586979 0.969156381555276
    0.999815929196087 0.966143308438322
    1.01840762385923 0.96167588822653
    1.02422624912665 0.959879519150392
    1.04820841787849 0.950503937405069
    1.05040526585597 0.949488520832702
    1.05188064663965 0.948792015052305
    1.06421741151945 0.942513866116551
    1.06952744475091 0.939564533487357
    1.07377729763307 0.937098333090976
    1.10837980144772 0.913625640841771
    1.12655613304724 0.898983298828636
    1.13577066384758 0.89098627132941
    1.1580472276478 0.870142330490693
    1.15859589504013 0.869603007065865
    1.18051156035791 0.847100007296536
    1.21401730562959 0.809369022407148
    1.33027028384446 0.656408242977467
    1.33483660875034 0.649970375448687
    1.37629546726956 0.590995765951455
    1.39873034424263 0.558976024508442
    1.42011477374599 0.528607866819228
    1.49811243643743 0.421418636969251
    1.55782976646071 0.345795703108512
    1.60683136399288 0.289407680329164
    1.67872959183145 0.217237684951087
    1.70586524394617 0.193407783948843
    2.09859653835273 0.0221208957939459
    2.23050096301146 0.0087062390469457
    };
    \addlegendentry{n=5};

    \addplot [
    color=green!50!black,
    solid,
    line width=1.5pt
    ]
    table{
    1.11061716777245 0.25439255248339
    1.32152703852018 0.444545345197107
    1.33743602693433 0.460242989969573
    1.42547263125263 0.547313752669856
    1.50599624519356 0.623697850962722
    1.5261804928616 0.641779387498937
    1.573838875732 0.682042674974274
    1.57730219814673 0.684816482012706
    1.62699159305991 0.721956657982538
    1.63486458952984 0.727347067179288
    1.68630344515834 0.758807092685913
    1.71784982886711 0.774600265244482
    1.83289913575602 0.806644546215021
    1.86864417529802 0.807887335418516
    1.88963804306077 0.806645110709114
    1.90172633188334 0.805269969440086
    1.97361138903204 0.787332803216098
    2.16847522483986 0.665794197723055
    2.26107642525521 0.582137894844234
    2.44093902647085 0.40561167899897
    2.55728899719626 0.299162501222641
    2.72596462417501 0.174351769994033
    3.14460320890567 0.0275718440302502
    };
    \addlegendentry{n=10};

    \addplot [
    color=red,
    solid,
    line width=1.5pt
    ]
    table{
    1.58873251442874 0.139270685555603
    1.75094674410523 0.187648610352166
    2.00056999517431 0.274533946251121
    2.27705604989095 0.374550491086161
    2.29596621491152 0.380969240114346
    2.41176717604408 0.417753266892818
    2.41614828744096 0.419044488634782
    2.45981848928711 0.431445200552556
    2.51461996380818 0.44569150663875
    2.63732800530387 0.471433199097579
    2.67540149916467 0.47748693150892
    2.72686458640717 0.484091305194831
    3.03140642922051 0.483465535521604
    3.07384878732821 0.477986374915163
    3.1895413994593 0.4569517259234
    3.25640618890004 0.441099033384993
    3.39991043346777 0.399612809225554
    3.7029148147097 0.292622994026572
    3.94491621538283 0.206344381423128
    4.36469219413918 0.0911022396340956
    4.68444030939428 0.0408178745872097
    };
    \addlegendentry{n=15};

    \addplot [
    color=mycolor1,
    solid,
    line width=1.5pt
    ]
    table{
    2.44469092422533 0.134047643683245
    2.99469910210473 0.332559909167666
    3.05373235366556 0.355888865309276
    3.31377765482139 0.447946402923478
    3.41066336498647 0.474278454032695
    3.73828133650772 0.512840458011838
    4.11146934521349 0.451592119764443
    4.12204843744243 0.448459021945289
    4.13062375797785 0.445874763291985
    4.34434429091486 0.371194128891267
    5.24212616032033 0.0753126892773911
    };
    \addlegendentry{n=20};

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%

    \end{document}
```

[image]

**BUT:**

If i do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering\makebox[\textwidth]
  {\resizebox{1.2\textwidth}{!}{%
  \begin{tabularx}{1.2\textwidth}{*2X}
  \begin{center}
  \subfloat[Normal distribution at n=5,10,15,20]{\label{fig:normpdf_3d}\input{./Figures/chapter6/normpdf_3d.tex}}\\%width=6cm,height=7.59cm
  \subfloat[Probability frequency density plot at n=5,10,15,20]{\label{fig:normpdf_2d}\input{./Figures/chapter6/normpdf_2d.tex}}%width=7.38cm,height=4.97cm
   \end{center}
 \end{tabularx}}}
 \smallskip
  \caption{PDF and scatter plots}
  \label{fig:normpdf}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I get some stupid error:
[image]

Any thoughts would be extremely helpful.

Just showing --shell-escape is truned on.
[image]

IMPORTANT NOTE:
The file compiles *correctly* **without** `\usepgfplotslibrary{external} \tikzexternalize` [sic]. Do I have to put something into the preamble of the file that I call? ie \input{normpdf_3d.tex}?

Comment: Gives the same problem... Do I need to add some sort of preamble to my normpdf_3d.tex file with my tikz commands in it?

Comment: It's in the first post... I'm actually only looking at normpdf_2d.tex at the moment, but haven't commented the other out in the last picture. ie from `\begin{tikzpicture}` to `\end{tikzpicture}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- To make your life easier, create a package (`mytikz`) for your drawing.

  ```
  % mytikz.sty
  % ========================================================
  % Copyright (c) 2013 Your Name. All rights reservered.
  % LPPL LaTeX Public Project License
  % ========================================================
  \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01] 
  \ProvidesPackage{mytikz}[2013/03/28 v0.01 Package for my TikZ configuration]

  \RequirePackage{pgfplots}
  \definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0,0.75,0.75}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
  \endinput
  ```
- Use `standalone` document class in the child (`myimage.tex`) and load `mytikz` package.

  ```
  % myimage.tex

  \documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
  \usepackage{mytikz}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]

  \begin{axis}[%
  width=4.52083333333333in,
  height=3.565625in,
  scale only axis,
  xmin=0, xmax=6,
  xlabel={cfu (Y)},
  ymin=0, ymax=1,
  ylabel={Probability density},
  legend style={draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left}
  ]
  \addplot [
  color=blue,
  solid,
  line width=1.5pt
  ]
  table{
  0.164920894751145 0.145245471693298
  0.34898483521757 0.314105513485571
  0.400206868657802 0.375704063846473
  0.431202365194672 0.415565960090126
  0.468283168514601 0.465368046385591
  0.468819173063357 0.466102333522882
  0.541086963948335 0.567617590141928
  0.558035142464694 0.591815958738304
  0.558424656178589 0.592372256340699
  0.567763246195775 0.605704754250354
  0.588442297122976 0.635140815037755
  0.588968308388865 0.635887013738116
  0.589496900268574 0.636636709024852
  0.615575125108802 0.673361419528354
  0.656478830152384 0.729356371745445
  0.663734249176834 0.739001710618186
  0.681134429788414 0.761691427683771
  0.699206339854542 0.784509230520803
  0.703174714510729 0.789406773282464
  0.710293205919594 0.798082837552696
  0.738324318268112 0.830765143080553
  0.743729355370618 0.836772857231647
  0.7628624687978 0.857202030543563
  0.789650071275085 0.883431847212714
  0.848769035460717 0.93014828764704
  0.857054257851899 0.935346913150545
  0.867490832222506 0.941393771927579
  0.892221633180695 0.953428704494102
  0.910732799951076 0.96026629015755
  0.942439202692875 0.967534739622871
  0.964173551423469 0.969220797343017
  0.966490207360103 0.969241291138126
  0.972340307586979 0.969156381555276
  0.999815929196087 0.966143308438322
  1.01840762385923 0.96167588822653
  1.02422624912665 0.959879519150392
  1.04820841787849 0.950503937405069
  1.05040526585597 0.949488520832702
  1.05188064663965 0.948792015052305
  1.06421741151945 0.942513866116551
  1.06952744475091 0.939564533487357
  1.07377729763307 0.937098333090976
  1.10837980144772 0.913625640841771
  1.12655613304724 0.898983298828636
  1.13577066384758 0.89098627132941
  1.1580472276478 0.870142330490693
  1.15859589504013 0.869603007065865
  1.18051156035791 0.847100007296536
  1.21401730562959 0.809369022407148
  1.33027028384446 0.656408242977467
  1.33483660875034 0.649970375448687
  1.37629546726956 0.590995765951455
  1.39873034424263 0.558976024508442
  1.42011477374599 0.528607866819228
  1.49811243643743 0.421418636969251
  1.55782976646071 0.345795703108512
  1.60683136399288 0.289407680329164
  1.67872959183145 0.217237684951087
  1.70586524394617 0.193407783948843
  2.09859653835273 0.0221208957939459
  2.23050096301146 0.0087062390469457
  };
  \addlegendentry{n=5};

  \addplot [
  color=green!50!black,
  solid,
  line width=1.5pt
  ]
  table{
  1.11061716777245 0.25439255248339
  1.32152703852018 0.444545345197107
  1.33743602693433 0.460242989969573
  1.42547263125263 0.547313752669856
  1.50599624519356 0.623697850962722
  1.5261804928616 0.641779387498937
  1.573838875732 0.682042674974274
  1.57730219814673 0.684816482012706
  1.62699159305991 0.721956657982538
  1.63486458952984 0.727347067179288
  1.68630344515834 0.758807092685913
  1.71784982886711 0.774600265244482
  1.83289913575602 0.806644546215021
  1.86864417529802 0.807887335418516
  1.88963804306077 0.806645110709114
  1.90172633188334 0.805269969440086
  1.97361138903204 0.787332803216098
  2.16847522483986 0.665794197723055
  2.26107642525521 0.582137894844234
  2.44093902647085 0.40561167899897
  2.55728899719626 0.299162501222641
  2.72596462417501 0.174351769994033
  3.14460320890567 0.0275718440302502
  };
  \addlegendentry{n=10};

  \addplot [
  color=red,
  solid,
  line width=1.5pt
  ]
  table{
  1.58873251442874 0.139270685555603
  1.75094674410523 0.187648610352166
  2.00056999517431 0.274533946251121
  2.27705604989095 0.374550491086161
  2.29596621491152 0.380969240114346
  2.41176717604408 0.417753266892818
  2.41614828744096 0.419044488634782
  2.45981848928711 0.431445200552556
  2.51461996380818 0.44569150663875
  2.63732800530387 0.471433199097579
  2.67540149916467 0.47748693150892
  2.72686458640717 0.484091305194831
  3.03140642922051 0.483465535521604
  3.07384878732821 0.477986374915163
  3.1895413994593 0.4569517259234
  3.25640618890004 0.441099033384993
  3.39991043346777 0.399612809225554
  3.7029148147097 0.292622994026572
  3.94491621538283 0.206344381423128
  4.36469219413918 0.0911022396340956
  4.68444030939428 0.0408178745872097
  };
  \addlegendentry{n=15};

  \addplot [
  color=mycolor1,
  solid,
  line width=1.5pt
  ]
  table{
  2.44469092422533 0.134047643683245
  2.99469910210473 0.332559909167666
  3.05373235366556 0.355888865309276
  3.31377765482139 0.447946402923478
  3.41066336498647 0.474278454032695
  3.73828133650772 0.512840458011838
  4.11146934521349 0.451592119764443
  4.12204843744243 0.448459021945289
  4.13062375797785 0.445874763291985
  4.34434429091486 0.371194128891267
  5.24212616032033 0.0753126892773911
  };
  \addlegendentry{n=20};

  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%

  \end{document}
  ```
- Use `standalone` (or `docmute`) package in the main file (`main.tex`) and load `mytikz` (the position is not important whether you put it before or after loading `standalone` (or `docmute`) package).

  ```
   % main.tex

   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage{subfig}
   \usepackage{tabularx}

   \usepackage{standalone}% or \usepackage{docmute}
   \usepackage{mytikz}

   \begin{document}


    \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering\makebox[\textwidth]
    {\resizebox{1.2\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabularx}{1.2\textwidth}{*2X}
    \begin{center}
    \subfloat[Normal distribution at n=5,10,15,20]      {\label{fig:normpdf_3d}\input{myimage.tex}}\\%width=6cm,height=7.59cm
    \subfloat[Probability frequency density plot at n=5,10,15,20]{\label{fig:normpdf_2d}\input{myimage.tex}}%width=7.38cm,height=4.97cm
    \end{center}
    \end{tabularx}}}
    \smallskip
    \caption{PDF and scatter plots}
    \label{fig:normpdf}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
  ```

### Simulation

Just for a simulation purpose, I put the child `myimage.tex` contents, main `main.tex` contents  and the `mytikz` package contents in a single input file. The child and the package must be enclosed in `filecontents*` environment!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mytikz.sty}
% mytikz.sty
% ========================================================
% Copyright (c) 2013 Your Name. All rights reservered.
% LPPL LaTeX Public Project License
% ========================================================
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01] 
\ProvidesPackage{mytikz}[2013/03/28 v0.01 Package for my TikZ configuration]
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{pgfplots}
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0,0.75,0.75}

\endinput
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{filecontents*}{myimage.tex}
    \documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
        \usepackage{mytikz}
        \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]

    \begin{axis}[%
    width=4.52083333333333in,
    height=3.565625in,
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0, xmax=6,
    xlabel={cfu (Y)},
    ymin=0, ymax=1,
    ylabel={Probability density},
    legend style={draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left}
    ]
    \addplot [
    color=blue,
    solid,
    line width=1.5pt
    ]
    table{
    0.164920894751145 0.145245471693298
    0.34898483521757 0.314105513485571
    0.400206868657802 0.375704063846473
    0.431202365194672 0.415565960090126
    0.468283168514601 0.465368046385591
    0.468819173063357 0.466102333522882
    0.541086963948335 0.567617590141928
    0.558035142464694 0.591815958738304
    0.558424656178589 0.592372256340699
    0.567763246195775 0.605704754250354
    0.588442297122976 0.635140815037755
    0.588968308388865 0.635887013738116
    0.589496900268574 0.636636709024852
    0.615575125108802 0.673361419528354
    0.656478830152384 0.729356371745445
    0.663734249176834 0.739001710618186
    0.681134429788414 0.761691427683771
    0.699206339854542 0.784509230520803
    0.703174714510729 0.789406773282464
    0.710293205919594 0.798082837552696
    0.738324318268112 0.830765143080553
    0.743729355370618 0.836772857231647
    0.7628624687978 0.857202030543563
    0.789650071275085 0.883431847212714
    0.848769035460717 0.93014828764704
    0.857054257851899 0.935346913150545
    0.867490832222506 0.941393771927579
    0.892221633180695 0.953428704494102
    0.910732799951076 0.96026629015755
    0.942439202692875 0.967534739622871
    0.964173551423469 0.969220797343017
    0.966490207360103 0.969241291138126
    0.972340307586979 0.969156381555276
    0.999815929196087 0.966143308438322
    1.01840762385923 0.96167588822653
    1.02422624912665 0.959879519150392
    1.04820841787849 0.950503937405069
    1.05040526585597 0.949488520832702
    1.05188064663965 0.948792015052305
    1.06421741151945 0.942513866116551
    1.06952744475091 0.939564533487357
    1.07377729763307 0.937098333090976
    1.10837980144772 0.913625640841771
    1.12655613304724 0.898983298828636
    1.13577066384758 0.89098627132941
    1.1580472276478 0.870142330490693
    1.15859589504013 0.869603007065865
    1.18051156035791 0.847100007296536
    1.21401730562959 0.809369022407148
    1.33027028384446 0.656408242977467
    1.33483660875034 0.649970375448687
    1.37629546726956 0.590995765951455
    1.39873034424263 0.558976024508442
    1.42011477374599 0.528607866819228
    1.49811243643743 0.421418636969251
    1.55782976646071 0.345795703108512
    1.60683136399288 0.289407680329164
    1.67872959183145 0.217237684951087
    1.70586524394617 0.193407783948843
    2.09859653835273 0.0221208957939459
    2.23050096301146 0.0087062390469457
    };
    \addlegendentry{n=5};

    \addplot [
    color=green!50!black,
    solid,
    line width=1.5pt
    ]
    table{
    1.11061716777245 0.25439255248339
    1.32152703852018 0.444545345197107
    1.33743602693433 0.460242989969573
    1.42547263125263 0.547313752669856
    1.50599624519356 0.623697850962722
    1.5261804928616 0.641779387498937
    1.573838875732 0.682042674974274
    1.57730219814673 0.684816482012706
    1.62699159305991 0.721956657982538
    1.63486458952984 0.727347067179288
    1.68630344515834 0.758807092685913
    1.71784982886711 0.774600265244482
    1.83289913575602 0.806644546215021
    1.86864417529802 0.807887335418516
    1.88963804306077 0.806645110709114
    1.90172633188334 0.805269969440086
    1.97361138903204 0.787332803216098
    2.16847522483986 0.665794197723055
    2.26107642525521 0.582137894844234
    2.44093902647085 0.40561167899897
    2.55728899719626 0.299162501222641
    2.72596462417501 0.174351769994033
    3.14460320890567 0.0275718440302502
    };
    \addlegendentry{n=10};

    \addplot [
    color=red,
    solid,
    line width=1.5pt
    ]
    table{
    1.58873251442874 0.139270685555603
    1.75094674410523 0.187648610352166
    2.00056999517431 0.274533946251121
    2.27705604989095 0.374550491086161
    2.29596621491152 0.380969240114346
    2.41176717604408 0.417753266892818
    2.41614828744096 0.419044488634782
    2.45981848928711 0.431445200552556
    2.51461996380818 0.44569150663875
    2.63732800530387 0.471433199097579
    2.67540149916467 0.47748693150892
    2.72686458640717 0.484091305194831
    3.03140642922051 0.483465535521604
    3.07384878732821 0.477986374915163
    3.1895413994593 0.4569517259234
    3.25640618890004 0.441099033384993
    3.39991043346777 0.399612809225554
    3.7029148147097 0.292622994026572
    3.94491621538283 0.206344381423128
    4.36469219413918 0.0911022396340956
    4.68444030939428 0.0408178745872097
    };
    \addlegendentry{n=15};

    \addplot [
    color=mycolor1,
    solid,
    line width=1.5pt
    ]
    table{
    2.44469092422533 0.134047643683245
    2.99469910210473 0.332559909167666
    3.05373235366556 0.355888865309276
    3.31377765482139 0.447946402923478
    3.41066336498647 0.474278454032695
    3.73828133650772 0.512840458011838
    4.11146934521349 0.451592119764443
    4.12204843744243 0.448459021945289
    4.13062375797785 0.445874763291985
    4.34434429091486 0.371194128891267
    5.24212616032033 0.0753126892773911
    };
    \addlegendentry{n=20};

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{standalone}% or \usepackage{docmute}
\usepackage{mytikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering\makebox[\textwidth]
  {\resizebox{1.2\textwidth}{!}{%
  \begin{tabularx}{1.2\textwidth}{*2X}
  \begin{center}
  \subfloat[Normal distribution at n=5,10,15,20]{\label{fig:normpdf_3d}\input{myimage.tex}}\\%width=6cm,height=7.59cm
  \subfloat[Probability frequency density plot at n=5,10,15,20]{\label{fig:normpdf_2d}\input{myimage.tex}}%width=7.38cm,height=4.97cm
   \end{center}
 \end{tabularx}}}
 \smallskip
  \caption{PDF and scatter plots}
  \label{fig:normpdf}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you sooooooooooooo much! I have spent all day with this, I'm so happy now! Would you mind explaining to me why you need to put a preamble in the figure file though? This I don't understand (though clearly it works!)

Comment: @HCAI: see my update, read it carefully!

Comment: @HCAI: each file is separately compilable so it needs `\documentclass`, which in turn, needs the required packages.

Comment: I'm experiencing an error which refers to insufficient room in an internal buffer but both figures compile fine on their own. it's only when they are put together and compiled from main.tex. Is this surmountable somehow?